# IP Command set gatway

Tags: linux, shell, networking, ip, gateway

I want to set the gateway to the particular interface via shell script.

We can modify the ethernet configuration file like this

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR=20:89:84:c8:12:8a
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
IPADDR=192.168.0.108
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS1=8.8.4.4
```

But I want to do it the `ip` command way. What will be the equivalent `ip` command to achieve this?

Comment: What does this question have to do with software development? I think you asked on the wrong SE site.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with [this little intro](http://www.tecmint.com/ip-command-examples/) to the ip commands or [this ip commands cheat sheet](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_ip_command_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print.pdf). With those, you can set IPADDR, e.g.

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.108 dev eth0
```

The GATEWAY is set by

```
sudo ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
```

The `sudo` is needed only, if the user is not root.

More work is to be done for the rest and not all of them are `ip` commands. E.g. DNS servers are set in the [`/etc/resolv.conf` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf) and not by an `ip` command.